# How to keep Qt thread alive when device sleeps

Tags: android, qt, qthread, java-threads

Here is diagram from Bogdan Vatra blog entry "Qt on Android Episode 7".

[image: Qt on Android Architecture diagram]

I want to have active `QEventLoop` & signal/slot processing when app at background or when device sleeps. Seems that Android API WakeLock's cant help, since it affects only Android thread.

*Update:* So, i tried to create separate thread (`QThread`) with worker object (QObject-derived) moved to that thread and it works. Signal/slot processing in worker object active while main Qt thread sleeps.

Comment: Are the signal/slot connections contained inside the work thread, or are they crossing thread-boundaries?

Comment: Looks like i miss that, when testing i used connections to object from different thread and  QElapsedTimer in worker to count thread execution time (but timer was freezing in worker object thread, which is strange)